# JS, вопрос по стрелочным выражениям

Tags: javascript

`email => users.find(user => user.email === email)`

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делает(или возвращает данное выражение). users - массив объектов user(содержит email, password, id). Интересует что получится в результате выполнения кода.
Upd. Не понятно остаётся что происходит в скобках find

Comment: что передадут, тому и  будет равен

Comment: нет, email - это параметр функции, что передадут при вызове функции - тому и будет равен

Comment: почему бы просто не выполнить и не посмотреть? :)

Comment: в данном случае нет никакой разницы массив или бд

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin понял, но ответ уже получен, по этому думаю сейчас исправлять нет смысла

Comment: улучшить вопрос можно в любой момент.

Comment: @n33t Александр заботится о качестве вопросов и ответов. Вам что, трудно добавить в вопрос строчку кода?

Comment: @Igor Не трудно, изменил

Comment: @n33t Молодец. Спасибо.

Comment: @Igor, `Вам что, трудно добавить в вопрос строчку кода?` — это у вас такая тонкая ирония (на фоне вашего ответа без строчки пояснений)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function(email) { 
  return users.find(function(user) { 
    return user.email === email; 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но не подскажете, как при return user.email ===email, где мы получаем true либо false, в результате find(function(user), возвращающем true или false), по итогу мы получили нужную нам структуру user?

Comment: @n33t https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Чтобы сэкономить Вам щелчки мыши: Я не буду стараться оставлять ... и так далее.

Comment: Не вижу проблем с ответами, всё максимально коротко и ясно :)

Comment: своими комментариями под вашими ответами низкого качестве я преследую три основных цели: 1. побудить вас улучшить качество ответов, и чаще писать пояснения прямо в тексте ответа (а не в комментариях или вообще нигде). 2. немного нивелировать вред от дурного примера, который вы такими сверхлаконичными ответами подаёте новичкам. 3. продемонстировать (тем же новичкам), что здесь нет к ним предвзятости за те же низкокачественные ответы, и просьбу улучшить ответ может получить любой участник. // персонально к вам имеет отношение всего лишь одна из трёх целей (первая в списке, но не главная).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Спасибо.

Comment: @n33t, то, что вам всё понятно в (даже столь лаконичном) ответе, — это, конечно, замечательно. а как насчёт десятков-сотен-... других людей, у которых может возникнуть аналогичный вашему вопрос, и которые из поисковиков попадут на эту страницу? не смогут ли им всем помочь хотя бы краткие (но в данный момент, увы, отсутствующие) пояснения к ответу?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Они совершат небольшое умственное усилие, и им тоже станет всё понятно.

Comment: на вопрос «почему трава зелёная?» можно ответить по-разному. и между двумя крайностями — а) «потому что» и б) длинным трактатом про хлорфилл, фотосинтез, преломление волн на границах сред и т.п. — лежит много промежуточных стадий. // возвращаясь к нашему сайту: да, надо выбирать какую-то «золотую середину» из множества всех возможных ответов. и тут, мне кажется, мы можем ориентироваться на демократические принципы: какого типа ответы получают [больше всего голосов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa). насколько я лично вижу, сверх-краткие ответы тут явно не в фаворе.